# Opencv haar training parameters : Mode & symmentry

Tags: image-processing, opencv3.0, feature-detection, haar-classifier, cascade-classifier

I am using Opencv 3.0
Before beginning training i wanted to set 'mode' parameter to 'all'
below is the command line argument

> C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc12\bin\opencv_traincascade.exe -data cascade
>   -numStages 20 -vec samples.vec -bg NegativeSet.txt -precalcValBufSize 3750 -precalcIdxBufSize 3750 -numPos 333 -numNeg 922 -minHitRate 0.995
>   -maxfalsealarm 0.5 -w 36 -h 28 -mode ALL

even though i am explicitly specifying mode parameter it still uses default value (BASIC), as u can see below

```
D:\>C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc12\bin\opencv_traincascade.exe -data cascade -numStages 20 -vec samples.vec -bg NegativeSet.txt -precalcValBufSize 3750 -precalcIdxBufSize 3750 -numPos 333 -numNeg 922 -minHi
tRate 0.995 -maxfalsealarm 0.5 -w 36 -h 28 -mode All
PARAMETERS:
cascadeDirName: cascade
vecFileName: samples.vec
bgFileName: NegativeSet.txt
numPos: 333
numNeg: 922
numStages: 20
precalcValBufSize[Mb] : 3750
precalcIdxBufSize[Mb] : 3750
stageType: BOOST
featureType: HAAR
sampleWidth: 36
sampleHeight: 28
boostType: GAB
minHitRate: 0.995
maxFalseAlarmRate: 0.5
weightTrimRate: 0.95
maxDepth: 1
maxWeakCount: 100
mode: BASIC
```

my second question is, How to use -nonsym ?
if i append -nonsym at the end or anywhere between command line argument, training crashes once i pass the arguments (as soon as i hit enter in cmd)
it says "opencv_traincascade.exe has stopped working"

below is the cmd line argument including -nonsym

> C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc12\bin\opencv_traincascade.exe -data cascade
>   -numStages 20 -vec samples.vec -bg NegativeSet.txt -precalcValBufSize 3750 -precalcIdxBufSize 3750 -numPos 333 -numNeg 922 -minHitRate 0.995
>   -maxfalsealarm 0.5 -w 36 -h 28 -mode ALL -nonsym

Thanks & regards